# Why does my "remote" machine have an ESTABLISHED connection to my dev machine?

Tags: c#, sockets, serversocket

I have created a simple "proof of concept" app that sends a text message over sockets using C# between two Windows computers (XP sending, W2K receiving).

When I run "netstat -a" on the receiving computer, I see a couple of strange things:

netstat tells me:

```
... 
TCP <thismachinename>:netbios-ssn   <DevMachineName>:1330   ESTABLISHED
...
```

--and:

```
TCP <thismachinename>:1041  a65.197.244.82.deploy.akamaitechologies.com:http    CLOSE_WAIT
```

So:
1) Why is there a connection with my Dev machine (It SHOULD be listening on port 62222, but it's not, yet this mysterious ESTABLISHED connection does exist...)
2) Who/what/why is this akamai technologies connection?

Note: I restarted the remote/listening machine this morning; I checked netstat -a to be sure it was not listening on port 62222 yet (it wasn't); I then started the dual-purpose app that should listen on that port; I ran netstat -a again, and it was STILL not listening on port 62222. Yet these other two odd things...

Answer (score 1):

The established connection to `<thismachinename>:netbios-ssn` is because you have connected to a Windows Share, printer or something on `thismachinename` from `DevMachineName`.

The second connection is that your computer has for some reason connected and downloaded something from akamai. The connection is closed, but in CLOSE_WAIT mode which it is for 120 seconds (if I remember the timeout correctly).

For the listening on port 62222 that is not appearing - do you get any errors in your app when you are opening the listening socket?

Comment: Yes, the error is that the other computer actively rejected the connection. The really bizarre/macabre thing is that this code is virtually identical to another app that works just fine - the difference in the code comes later, after the connection is made - or not made, as the case may be (so it doesn't run at all in the non-functioning app)